# XML API to PHP! New developer, no idea how to do this

Tags: php, xml, api, parsing

Simple question, I should think. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to get it working.

I have an xml data sheet that looks like this:

```
<leads>
    <leadDetails>
        <lead_id>3886961</lead_id>
        <campaign_id>1173</campaign_id>
        <campaign_name>Tesco vs Argos - Submit (UK)</campaign_name>
        <subID>N/A</subID>
        <gateway>yes</gateway>
        <ip>109.155.249.140</ip>
        <referring_url>http://adworkmedia.com/gTemplate.php?GID=1514&pubID=2312&sid=&ST=
        </referring_url>
        <date>2012-03-24 07:19:07</date>
        <payout>$0.70</payout>
        <status>Credited</status>
    </leadDetails>
</leads>
```

I should add that this XML sheet is not hosting on my servers, but is dynamically updated as I get a new lead, by my network. Feel free to ask me more questions if needed.

MY QUESTION IS: How can I write a code that reads the XML page, and uploads, for each , the date, the IP, and the campaign_name to a mySQL table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi.

```
           if( $xml = simplexml_load_file("the_url_of_xml"))
            {
              foreach($xml->leads->leadDetails as $detail) 
              {   
                $camp_id = $detail->campaign_id;
                $camp_name = $detail->campaign_name;
                $sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (id,name) VALUES ('$camp_id','$camp_name')";//AND so on
                mysql_query($sql);
            }

           }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good tutorial to start with 
[Link to tutorial](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/handling-xml-data)

Answer (score 1):

Just a starting point for your reference, using SimpleXML and PDO:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://yourhost.com/somefile.xml');
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost', 'user', 'pass');
foreach ($xml->leadDetails as $lead) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (createdAt, ip, campaign_name) VALUES (NOW(), ?, ?)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        $lead->campaign_name
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON would be a better format in my opinion, but for XML, it's pretty simple.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("username","password","host");
mysql_select_db("database_name",$con);

$xmlObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml); //replace $xml with your XML string.
foreach($xmlObj->leadDetails as $details){
    $date = $details->date;
    $ip = $details->ip;
    $campaign_name = $details->campaign_name;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table_name` (`date`,`ip`,`campaign_name`) VALUES ('$date','$ip','$campaign_name')",$con);
}
?>
```